# Update statement not providing correct result in a BTEQ after Teradata 15 upgradation

Tags: teradata

An update statement is not working when executed inside BTEQ after Teradata 15 upgrade. The statement gives required output if executed from SQL Assistant manually. The statement is having a simple code.

---Update statement

```
UPDATE MAIN2
        FROM 
            PSE_BIX_ABT.TP_ABT_DT_MOB_SBSCR_MAIN2 AS MAIN2,
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    SBSCR_ID,  
                    ( SELECT DT FROM PSE_BIX_ABT.TP_ABT_DT_MOB_SBSCR_DT WHERE ID = 1 ) AS SNAP_DT,
                    SRVC_PRVDR_ID AS PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_ID,
                    SRVC_PRVDR_NM AS PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_NM,
                    OREPLACE(OREPLACE(SRVC_PRVDR_DESC,'[Fixed]',''),'[Mobile]','') AS PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_DESC,
                    PORT_STRT_DT AS PORTED_IN_DT,
                    CASE
                        WHEN PORTED_IN_DT = SNAP_DT THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                    END AS PORTED_IN_CNT
                FROM 
                    PSE_BIX_SL_VW.V_F_PORTED_SBSCRS AS PORTED_SBSCR
                INNER JOIN 
                    PSE_BIX_SL_VW.V_SRVC_PRVDR SRVC
                    ON PORTED_SBSCR.DNR_SRVC_PRVDR_ID = SRVC.SRVC_PRVDR_ID
                WHERE 
                    PORT_IN_FL  = 1
                    AND SBSCR_ID <> -1
                    AND PORT_STRT_DT <= ( SELECT DT FROM PSE_BIX_ABT.TP_ABT_DT_MOB_SBSCR_DT WHERE ID = 1 )
                    AND (SBSCR_ID,PORT_STRT_DT) IN (SEL SBSCR_ID,MAX(PORT_STRT_DT) FROM PSE_BIX_SL_VW.V_F_PORTED_SBSCRS WHERE PORT_STRT_DT <=   ( SELECT DT FROM PSE_BIX_ABT.TP_ABT_DT_MOB_SBSCR_DT WHERE ID = 1 )  GROUP BY 1 )
            ) D_PORT_IN
        SET 
            PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_ID = D_PORT_IN.PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_ID,
            PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_NM = D_PORT_IN.PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_NM,
            PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_DESC = D_PORT_IN.PORTED_IN_DNR_SP_DESC,
            PORTED_IN_DT = D_PORT_IN.PORTED_IN_DT,
            PORTED_IN_CNT = D_PORT_IN.PORTED_IN_CNT
        WHERE 
            MAIN2.SBSCR_ID = D_PORT_IN.SBSCR_ID
            AND MAIN2.SNAP_DT = D_PORT_IN.SNAP_DT;
```

Kindly help on the same.
Current Teradata 15.10.04.05 (Upgraded from 14)

Comment: What does _not working_ mean? Incorrect results?  Error message?

Comment: There is no error msg. Data is not getting updated.
Activity count is 0. update is not working from SQL assistant either. I mentioned wrong earlier. 
 But it was working in TD14.  

If we write one more select on the top of  D_PORT_IN and derive snap_DT and PORTED_IN_CNT outside and all other 3 columns from D_PORT_IN and alias source as A and use the SNAP_DT from A in last where clause, it works.

Query also works if we comment  AND MAIN2.SNAP_DT = D_PORT_IN part, just a check to confirm snap DT is getting passed null from inner derivation somehow